# Stuck on boot after adding fsck.mode=force

Tags: boot, 20.04, fsck

Inside the grub menu, I used <kbd>e</kbd> to add `fsck.mode=force` to the `linux` line and continued booting. As a result, the screen only shows a blinking cursor in the upper left for 10 hours now. Disk led is off 99.9% of the time and blinks every now and then like once every 30 seconds.

It’s Ubuntu 20.04 on a dual boot samsung 960 pro 512GB (nvme).

Is this just normal and I simply have to wait or what should I do to go on?

Comment: sounds to me like you have a dead/dying disk.   I'd try and safely reboot, boot *live* and check the health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  even if it's not dead/dying.. it's where I'd start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a reboot and repeat of the process, `fsck` finished within 10 seconds (no errors). Maybe fsck invisibly waited for input or the stuck boot process had nothing to do with fsck at all.